# Getting the Name of a .txt file and echoeing just the name

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make a batch file that saves what you say to it then makes a .txt file with the name of the question you asked. Then I want the batch file to get the file name without the extension and echo it back to the user. Is this possible?

Comment: Just being honest before people start coming along and downvoting you.

Comment: Sounds like an easy task. What is the problem specifically? If it's `do it all for me, please` then SO is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: Since your question is apparently "is this possible," I will answer with a simple "yes."

Comment: I looked up how to do it and most of the ways to do it were to general and not the specific task I wanted. I was just wondering if you could set me on the right path and I would figure it out from there. Thanks anyway though for your feedback, I found the syntax I needed.